# Regex URL in django doesnt work

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-urls

i have this in my URL config:

```
url(r'^fotogalerie/(?P<nazev_slozky>([^/]+/)+)/$', fotogalerie_slozka),
```

I want to work for all URL that begin at fotogalerie, so for "fotogalerie/something/","fotogalerie/so/on/","fotogalerie/i/don't know/anything/". Why this isnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requiring two trailing slashes, since your path subcomponents have to end with one in the subgroup definition and then you also have `/$` at the end of your pattern.  Depending on what your pattern should contain, either remove the final `/` or use a named group that has the final `/` optional.

That is, either:

```
url(r'^fotogalerie/(?P<nazev_slozky>([^/]+/)+)$', fotogalerie_slozka),
```

if you want your captured argument to be `so/on/`, or:

```
url(r'^fotogalerie/(?P<nazev_slozky>([^/]+/?)+)/$', fotogalerie_slozka),
```

if you want your captured argument to be `so/on`.